# Error on android studio gradle progress

Tags: javascript, java, android, ide

I want to add a library but when I click on the sync appears this error, bad for an English speaking sorry

My error details:

> Error:(39, 13) Failed to resolve: com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1

Screenshot:

[image: my error image]

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mypackagename"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
useLibrary(
        'org.apache.http.legacy'
)
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

[}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: \['*.jar'\], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'

}
```

Comment: Is floatingactionbutton a library project?

Comment: @KanchanChowdhury yes

Comment: Library projects are added as following:
 compile project(':project name')

Comment: @KanchanChowdhury I'm going to use this link [link](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button/blob/master/README.md)